# How to refresh MaterialTable component data after the state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I have a parent Node component and I want to change the data in the MaterialTable everytime the **refresh** state is change. To be more exact, I want to call the api which is getNodes everytime the **refresh** state is change and make the MaterialTable to be refresh.

```
const Node = () =>{
                   const [refresh,setRefresh] = useState(false);


                   const getNodes = (query) =>
new Promise((resolve, ) => {
  let url_qp = "?";
  url_qp += "per_page=" + query.pageSize;
  url_qp += "&page=" + (query.page + 1);
  url_qp += "&keyword=" + query.search.toUpperCase();
  // console.log(query);
  if (query.filters.length !== 0) {
    let type_filter = query.filters[0].value.toUpperCase();
    url_qp += "&type=" + type_filter;
  }
  let type = query.orderBy ? query.orderBy.field : "";
  GetFilterNodes(url_qp)
    .then((response) => {
      resolve({
        data: sortArray(response.data.nodes, type, query.orderDirection),
        page: response.data.page - 1,
        totalCount: response.data.total_count,
      });
    })
    .catch(globalErrorHandler);
}); 


       return (
<div>
  <MaterialTable
    title="Node List"
    columns={columns}
    data={getNodes}
    options={{
      actionsColumnIndex: -1,
      pageSize: 10,
      pageSizeOptions: [10, 20, 50, 100],
      emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,
      debounceInterval: 700,
      filtering: true,
    }}
    actions={action}
  />
 
    );


                   }
```